# Magento: is it possible to get credit card processing AVS and CSC?

Tags: php, magento

I'd like to get credit card processing AVS and CSC results (pass/no pass, yes/no, etc.)  printed on our invoice PDF, but I have no idea if they are available from Magento at all. I don't see it on the backend admin section under the sales orders.

I'm working on this file for the PDF invoice:

`/var/www/html/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php`

Is it along the lines of `$order->getPayment()->...`?

*** UPDATE: ***

Payment gateway: Payflow Pro (by Paypal) - this is different from Paypal Express Checkout, where the buyer goes to paypal.com to make a payment.

Magento Enterprise 1.11.2.0

Comment: Which payment gateway, and module do you use? A magento version number will also help here.

Comment: print_r($order); and print_r($order->getPayment()); and see if you find what you are looking for.

Comment: @B00MER: I updated the post. Please take a look.

Comment: @Dreaded semicolon: how would I examine the array content of `$order` when I'm printing to a PDF? I supposed I could print `array_keys()` one by one to the PDF and find out which keys have which information, but is there an easier way to do this (like an arbitrary page I could load up with the order number, so I could just `print_r()` to the browser)?

Comment: add die(); after print_r  or use magento log.  or write the results to a file. I usually do the die() one . it's not ideal but fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should work , I found it using search for string AVS in magento paypal module

```
 $avs_response=$order->getPayment()->getAdditionalInformation('paypal_avs_code');
```

and paypal_cvv2_match / CSC?

```
 $csc_response=$order->getPayment()->getAdditionalInformation('paypal_cvv2_match');
```

Comment: Hm, this is not returning anything. I'm examining `$order->getPayment()->debug()`, but I don't see any mentions of `paypal_xxx`. `['additoinal_information']` is empty. Do you know why it would there in the array but left empty? `['additoinal_information']` is populated if the order is paid via Paypal. The transaction in question was paid by American Express.

Comment: American express processed by paypal right?   this is set when paypal process the payment.  if you search paypal_avs_code in magento paypal module, you ll see exactly where it is set.

Comment: AmEx processed by Payflow (someone uses credit card directly on our site) shows an empty `['additoinal_information']`. When someone uses Paypal express checkout (as in they go to paypal.com, log on, and commit payment), `['additoinal_information']` is populated, but it is information that I don't need. I haven't been able to locate what I need yet.. I don't see it in `$order->getPayment()`, but I can't really believe that such information unavailable.

Comment: Could you tell me where I need to look for the Payflow module? Maybe I can dig into the code and see what it's doing.

Comment: It seems it records avs only if it found N (declined) response, but it should record cv2 if response is not Y.   you can find this in `core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Payflowlink.php`   `function _processOrder` particularly line 208 (in version 1.5) `if ($response->getAvsdata()`

Comment: Very good! I did put in a real order with intentionally-incorrect 3-digit code for a Visa. The order went through, but it wasn't flagged. I supposed I can try a couple of other things, but I see what the program does now. Thanks.